# Is there a C++11 to C++03 converter?

Tags: c++, c++11, converters, c++03

Is there such a tool that is able to convert a code that uses some C++11 features to C++03 compatible code (perhaps using some third party libraries like Boost)?

Comment: No there is no tool as such, which I've heard of

Comment: As (relatively) easy as updating your toolchain is, seems like it wouldn't be worth the effort for anyone to ever create a converter. I *really* doubt there is one or ever will be a production quality one. Would be quite interesting though.

Comment: If you really want this badly enough, you could undoubtedly create a back-end for Clang that would emit C++03 code. The code it generated would probably only be suitable for consumption by a compiler though. Making it readable would probably be quite difficult.

Comment: @Corbin It is hard (or sometimes impossible) to run a c++11 program on a quite old system like Ubuntu 8.04 Server, so such a tool would be not so useless (though after a few years it will)

Comment: @szx, _running_ a program is not the same as _compiling_ a program. In any case, you can install a newer compiler on older systems easily enough, then you can compile C++11 code there.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Actually, it can be hard to run an old program because of shared library issues. IMHO, the solution to that is static linking or shipping the library you need with your program.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "hard" ... it just takes a bit of understanding what you're doing, which isn't such a big ask

Comment: Not everybody who runs the program may be able to build gcc from source and compile it on their ancient system

Comment: @szx Writing a C++11 to C++03 converter would be harder. A lot harder. Though it would of course be a lot more usable in the long run (5000x longer to make, but a million times more useful). At the end of the day, C++11 is just a really complicated language. I can't imagine anyone ever putting in the effort past hobby project (though I am wrong 99% of the time... lol).

Comment: Not a real question? It's just a yes/no question, what's so unreal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because nobody has answered with an actual answer, the answer is "No". Just upgrade your toolchain. There are a lot of good reasons to do that anyway.

For Ubuntu and other Linux variants, you can even download the package in source form and compile it for your ancient system if you want to use a new toolchain on a very old system. Of course, if you then ship programs with this you will have to link `libstdc++` statically or ship the shared library along with your program.

It's highly unlikely that anybody would ever write a converter since it's so easy to just upgrade your toolchain. It would be an interesting (and rather complex) hobby project. Maybe someone will someday write a C++11 compiler than compiles to C99. :-) That would probably be a whole lot easier.

Comment: A C++11-to-portable-C99 compiler is pretty much impossible. A C++11-to-system-specific-C99 compiler is probably not of any use. But a C++11-subset-to-portable-C99 compiler could be useful in a few rare situations, and very interesting regardless.

Comment: Linking libstdc++ statically doesn't always help, I once did this and some weird symbols were not found at runtime when ran on the older system

Comment: @szx If you dynamically link with a new glibc / libgcc, you cannot generally use the resulting binary on a system with an old glibc / libgcc. You'd need to install gcc on the old system, with the old glibc, and perform the build there. But that's not because of a statically linked libstdc++.

Comment: @hvd: Why is it pretty much impossible? `cfront` did it for an older version of C++.

Comment: @Omnifarious Most simply, C++ programs may be ill-formed (requiring a diagnostic) on one system but perfectly valid on another, depending on complex situations that cannot be expressed in C in such a way that it gets detected at compile time. As far as I know, cfront never emitted portable C; its output merely had to be correct for the one system it would be compiled on.

Comment: Your current C++ compiler generates assembly language, so a translation _is_ possible. Getting some kind of decent performance is probably harder (and pointless, you need the runtime support anyway)

Comment: @hvd: `_ZZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEjE10__fast_bkt` doesn't look like a glibc/libgcc symbol (though I may be wrong)

Comment: @szx You're right that that's part of libstdc++. If you statically link libstdc++ (and don't include anything that links to it dynamically), you can never get *that* as an unresolved symbol. However, I suspect your unresolved symbol wasn't that, but was coming *from* that: libstdc++ uses glibc / libgcc functions, and if you use `_M_next_bkt`, which gets statically linked into your application, but which dynamically links to a glibc / libgcc function not available on older systems, you may see `_M_next_bkt` in the error message as well.

Comment: @hvd Linking with static libgcc didn't change anything, `ldd` shows no dependencies on libstdc++ or libgcc... should I link to static libc then? already tried adding `-static-libc` but there doesn't seem to be such flag

Comment: @szx: Last I checked, `-static` would link everything statically, though I would add `-static-libgcc` just to be sure.

Comment: I will think it is somewhat very hard. Look at lambda and rvalue-references.

Comment: @Omnifarious I think another problem is the C++ exception system. I remembered it is the reason why Bell Lab stopped compiling C++ to C code.

Comment: The [Comeau C++ compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B) apparently still compiles to C. It only has partial support for C++11 though.